# Impose specific input method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, input, handwriting

In an application I want to have a text field where the input method always should be handwritten simplified chinese, even though the user probably haven't even activated this input method in the settings.

Is there a way to impose a specific input method?
`UITextField` has a property `inputView` which can be used for a custom input view, can also existing input methods' views be grabbed and set as `inputView`?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. Either use the default inputView (UIKeyboard) or create a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it's not possible, as phix23 wrote in a comment. The only option would be to create my own [custom input view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).